# Convert Keys.keycode to Virtualkeycode

Tags: vb.net, keydown, keycode

Going round in circle on this one. Can't post any solid code, because tried so many different approaches. Basically, trying to grab keystroke codes (Virtual and Keys) via (example code):

```
Private Sub DGVKeyHook(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As PreviewKeyDownEventArgs) Handles EmuKeyRemapDGV.PreviewKeyDown

        dim VCode as integer
        dim VCodeName as string
        dim KCode as integer
        dim KCodeName as String 

        Dim kc As New KeysConverter

        KCode = e.keycode
        KCodeName = kc.ConvertToString(e.KeyCode)
        'How to get the rest?

end sub
```

I need to preserve Left and Right distinction on Shift, Ctrl, Win + Alt. I know this can't be done for Keys.KeyCode. Also would like to get the Virtual Keycode name if possible (e.g. "VK_LSHIFT").

Here's some of the code I messed about with to try and achieve this, but all got messy - not sure any of this relevant to what trying to achieve:

```
<DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="VkKeyScanEx", CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)>
Friend Shared Function GetKeyCode(
                   ByVal c As Char,
                   Optional ByVal KeyboardLayout As UIntPtr = Nothing
     ) As Short
End Function

<DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
Public Shared Function MapVirtualKey(ByVal uCode As Integer, ByVal nMapType As Integer) As Integer
End Function

Public Shared Function GetLoByte(ByVal value As Short) As Byte
    Return BitConverter.GetBytes(value).First
End Function

 ' and in keys block:

        Dim RawVCode As Integer = GetKeyCode(ChrW(e.KeyCode))
        Dim LowVCode As Integer = GetLoByte(GetKeyCode(ChrW(e.KeyCode)))

        cfdb.echo("Raw Vcode: " & RawVCode)
        cfdb.echo("Low Vcode: " & LowVCode)
        cfdb.echo("MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC>>>>>>" & MapVirtualKey(e.KeyCode, 0))
```

Help really appreciated on this quagmire!

Comment: There is no distinction in the virtual key code between the left and right Shift keys.  They only have a different *scan code*, the number generated by the keyboard controller.  A quirk that goes back all the way to 1981 with the design of the first IBM PC.  So what you are trying to do is just not possible.

Comment: Maybe I'm getting terminology/concepts confused, but the msdn page would suggest otherwise? For instance - it has: VK_LSHIFT(0xA0) and VK_RSHIFT(0xA1). What I'm after is how to get these values and names when the key is pressed. The page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396